# Color loss and grayish after downscaling using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, color-correction, handbrake

Forgive me for I'm new to here, but I've been searching for solutions all the day,  yet still puzzled by this problem. I try to downscale a 3840*2160 video to 1080p, and here's what I first did:

`ffmpeg -i original.mkv -vf scale=1920:-1 downscaled.mkv`

And here are the results:

Original:
[image: Original video screenshot]

Downscaled:
[image: Downscaled video screenshot]

At first, I thought it's because I didn't apply the correct settings to my video player (potplayer), but even I set exactly the same splitter/decoder/renderer/..., it still didn't work.

Then I searched and tried different ways like  `pix_fmt yuv444p10le` which is from a [post here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28889/ffmpeg-does-not-preserve-colors-after-resizing), and later defined encoders, crf...... but all didn't work.

**Could anyone please help me, many thanks!**

---

Add: I then used HandBrake, a GUI video transcoder, to downscale the original video, it worked well, at least, looks a lot better.
[image: Downscaled video using HandBrake screenshot]

Comment: Interesting. I suspect it has something to do with the color-space you're in. The original footage might have been in srgb but then got converted into an ACES colorspace (for example), and thus the values for each color shifted a bit. You might want to try to find out the color-space of your original footage and then setting it during the downscaling with ffmpeg.

Comment: Share the readout of `ffmpeg -i original.mkv `

Comment: @Gyan too long to comment, so I'll separately comment.

Comment: `Metadata:
    title           : Frozen.II.2019.2160p.BluRay.REMUX.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-FGT
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:01:40.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 68129 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 100.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc`

Comment: `Metadata:
      title           : Frozen.II.2019.2160p.BluRay.REMUX.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-FGT
      BPS-eng         : 60669047
      DURATION-eng    : 01:43:13.646000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 148499
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 46970325317
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v43.0.0 ('The Quartermaster') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-02-15 09:08:44
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION   : 00:01:40.642000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit) (default)`

Comment: `Metadata:
      title           : Frozen.II.2019.2160p.BluRay.REMUX.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-FGT
      BPS-eng         : 8448778
      DURATION-eng    : 01:43:13.646000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 7432376
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 6541093050
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v43.0.0 ('The Quartermaster') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-02-15 09:08:44
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:01:40.336000000
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default)`

Comment: `Metadata:
      title           : English-SRT
      BPS-eng         : 53
      DURATION-eng    : 01:41:34.123000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1562
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 40405
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v43.0.0 ('The Quartermaster') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-02-15 09:08:44
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:01:39.221000000`

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add this info instead of trying to cram it in multiple comments.